# Write a binary image to a mat file - matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binary, matrix, save

I have an image which is in binary format. Width and height are 10 and 10. I want this image to write to a .mat file. When I save this image to a .mat file. It display as a 10x10 matrix. But, what I want is 100 values as a row or a column to be written to the .mat file, not 10x10 matrix. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any matrix into a vector like this:  `x(:)`.